# Web Platform with Livestream Integration Advice

Tags: web-applications, live-streaming

I'm looking for some advice on how to set up a site that has the following features:

- A web-based platform that embeds livestream video from a third party host such as Livestream, UStream etc.
- The livestream account will have multiple channels streaming that can be accessed from the web platform.
- The website acts as a platform that allows users to see upcoming shows and purchase a virtual ticket to have access to the livestream when it goes live.
- A sign up feature with users profiles
- Payment integration such as stripe.

**Process:** The user goes onto the site and can see all the upcoming shows in their area which are going to be livestreamed in the future. When a show goes live the user clicks on "Buy Virtual Ticket" where they are then prompted to sign up (or log in) and provide card information. After they have paid they get access to the livestream video.

The livestream hosting is all done by a third party and I want to integrate the different channels into my site.

What programming language would be best for this kind of project? What kind of skills should I look for when looking for a technical cofounder? How difficult of a project is this? Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are incredibly broad, and cannot be answered as-is.  There is not nearly enough information here to help you in any meaningful way.  Let me help break this down as best as I can and point out some things you should possibly be considering.

> Im looking for some advice

Stack Overflow isn't a place for advice.  It's a place where you come with a well defined problem, and get a solution.  I'm emphasizing this because this is how most technical implementers prefer to work as well.  It's good that you're looking for a technical co-founder, but I strongly recommend thoroughly working on the business plan.  Otherwise you risk the chance that nobody will take you seriously.  And, even if you do find someone, do you really want a co-founder to be the person that didn't question why you believe that reinventing an overdone model would be successful?  There's nothing outlined above, in my opinion, that is unique.  Surely there is something that differentiates your plan, and that needs to be known when you start discussing your project.

> The website acts as a platform that allows users to see upcoming shows and purchase a virtual ticket to have access to the livestream when it goes live.

Where will you get this data?  Many streaming platforms do not have the ability to schedule a show.  In any case, why would someone buy a ticket to something that they can just go to the source for?  Remember too that your terms of service agreements for embedding on most any streaming platform provider will require that you display their logos.

> A sign up feature with users profiles

This needs to be much more thoroughly defined.  Frankly, this is the sort of feature request that makes people cringe, as it's open-ended and almost always adds zero value to the product.  **Why** is this feature here?  What makes it **important** to the business?  If you don't have an answer to that question, integrate authentication with a handful of popular providers to lower your barrier of entry for users and move on.  On the other hand, if you have some sort of reason why profiles are important, you need to define that.

Also keep in mind that these are the types of features that tend to carry a heavy weight as far as development efforts go.  I could build you a database and a site for embedding streaming videos in an hour.  It might take a month to build some basic profile functionality.  Prioritize accordingly, which often means you'll be cutting everything that isn't critical to your business.

> Payment integration such as stripe.

Stripe is a great choice.  It's often one that the business folks and the tech folks can agree upon.  I haven't done a lot of payment gateway integrations myself... just PayPal and Stripe, and I found Stripe to be a lot easier.  That's just my opinion though... ask your team once you build it.

> What programming language would be best for this kind of project?

This is not an appropriate question to ask at all.  You can build this in practically any language.  What you have proposed is a perfectly generic CRUD web application that has no special functionality or requirements.

> What kind of skills should I look for when looking for a technical cofounder?

- Someone that has done this before
- Someone willing to disagree with you when it matters
- Someone that has a complementary skill set as yourself

> How difficult of a project is this?

Again, this goes back to how to ask a question.  If I were to say "easy", what would that mean to you?  If I were to say "hard", what would that mean to you?  I assume what you want to know is what sort of time and investment you're looking at, but that's not what you asked.  Even if you had asked that, it's impossible to tell you because there's almost no information here.  In fact, you haven't even indicated *specifically* what providers you want to integrate.  "etc." is not remotely sufficient.  It needs to be thought about and decided.

What you have posted is the starting point of a discussion.  Specific reliable answers cannot be given to vague open-ended questions.  It is also fair to say that you probably don't know what questions to ask yet, which is why you need to find someone to help you.

I sincerely hope this is helpful and gives you an idea of some things to consider as you go down this path.  Sometimes it's hard to get started, but if you can find the right help, you might be able to do so.